# jQuery 1.9.1 .ready() not firing in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, requirejs

According to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/),

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received.

I am using code where `$(handler)` is not working as expected, without apparent reason. Here is some code I run in the console:

```
>>> document.readyState
"complete"
>>> $(function () { console.log("A") })
[    #document    ]
>>> jQuery(function () { console.log("B") })
[    #document    ]
```

I would add that no `handler` in any `$().ready` written anywhere else will have been called at this point.

However, note when the following subsequent call is made:

```
>>> jQuery.ready()
A
B
```

At the same time, any other handlers elsewhere will also be called.

The ready handlers will now work as expected. i.e.

```
>>> $(function () { console.log("D"); }
D
```

I am just curious why jQuery may not be working in this case, if anyone has encountered anything similar, and how one might go about finding what may be interfering.

In the Chrome developer tools I am using, there do not appear to be any resources that have not loaded.

For whatever it's worth, the code is using RequireJS to asynchronously load scripts, including jQuery, though all the handlers are definitely defined after jQuery has been loaded (i.e. wrapped in a `define(['jquery'], ...)` or `require(['jquery'], ...)` equivalent.

#### Edit

I have noted that the issue occurs in Google Chrome, but not Firefox. I had, perhaps mistakenly, thought that the issue was also exhibiting in Firefox.

Grateful for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever it's worth, for the next folk to encounter this, the included `uservoice` code seems to have been clobbering the native jQuery calls, so `jQuery.ready()` would never be called.